# How to use webclient and debug and not get a targetinvocation exception?

Tags: silverlight, exception, target, invocation

I am debugging my silverlight app and have a webclient request that downloads a file say "www.blah.com/testfile.xml". I have the clientaccesspolicy.xml and crossdomain.xml files on the server so it works on the server just fine. When I debug the app on my local computer it generates a tagetinvocation exception. I put the clientaccesspolicy.xml and crossdomain.xml in my web project but this still generates this error when I am debugging. As a note when debugging I can see them on http://localhost/clientaccesspolicy.xml and http://localhost/crossdomain.xml, so I know they are in the right spot. Does anyone know how fix the exception?

Answer (score 0):

Blah. So... I was actually referencing "..\rest.php" which I figured out to get working in the web test app you have to have everything under the client_bin folder or you get the exception. So I changed it to "rest.php" and put a dummy xml file which will be a response back. I'm still having trouble with the designer view because my viewmodel starts loading the rest results in the viewmodel constructor and for some reason it doesn't like the path (still getting target invocation exception where it can't find the relative path "rest.php")

Comment: Yeah and more... If I add a try catch around the callback for the webclient then I can see it in blend designer view - of course the webclient fails to load the xml file, but hey I think that's ok.